# How can I force 2 fields in a Django model to share the same default value?

Tags: python, django, django-models, default

I have a Django model `MyModel` as shown below.

It has two fields of type DateTimeField: `my_field1`, `my_field2`

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field1 = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
    my_field2 = models.DateTimeField(
        # WHAT DO I PUT HERE?
    )
```

I want both fields to default to the value of `datetime.utcnow()`. But I want to save ***the same*** value for both. It seems wasteful to call `utcnow()` twice.

How can I set the default value of `my_field2` so that it simply copies the default value of `my_field1`?

Comment: Don't use default value for `Date/DateTime` fields. It gets cached and stays the same until the Python process don't get restarted. Use `auto_now` or `auto_now_add`.

Comment: @Todor he's using `default=datetime.utcnow` not `default=datetime.utcnow()` -- so the value is not "cached", but is calculated each time.

Comment: Aghh, True I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is by over riding the save method rather than the `__init__` method. In fact it's not recommended to over ride the **init** method, the better way is to over ride from_db if you wish to control how the objects are read or save method if you want to control how they are saved.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field1 = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
    my_field2 = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *arges, **kwargs):
        if self.my_field1 is None:
            self.my_field1 = datetime.utcnow()
            if self.my_field2 is None:
                self.my_field2 = self.my_field1

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Update: Reference for my claim: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/

> You may be tempted to customize the model by overriding the **init**
>   method. If you do so, however, take care not to change the calling
>   signature as any change may prevent the model instance from being
>   saved. Rather than overriding **init**, try using one of these
>   approaches:

Comment: > In fact it's not recommended to over ride the `__init__` method -- where did you get this from?

Comment: I would not call this "not recommended". Just warns to to keep the signature.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#default):

> The default value is used when new model instances are created and a value isn’t provided for the field.

So to solve your task, I would fill the default values manually in the `__init__`. Something like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    kwargs.setdefault('my_field1', now)
    kwargs.setdefault('my_field2', now)
    super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Alternatively you can handle the values in `save` method.

If you want `my_field2` to have any value that is in `my_field1`, I would go with this solution:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field1 = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
    my_field2 = models.DateTimeField()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if self.my_field2 is None:
            self.my_field2 = self.my_field1
```

Comment: Can you please modify your answer such that if `my_field2` defaults to whatever the value in `my_field1` is? If `my_field1` is provided, but `my_field2` is not, your solution doesn't copy the value from one to the other.

Comment: That constructor breaks the class. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802041/why-does-adding-this-constructor-break-my-django-model