# Why does adding this __init__() method break my Django model?

Tags: python, django, constructor

This question is a follow-up to one I asked earlier [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782083/how-can-i-force-2-fields-in-a-django-model-to-share-the-same-default-value).

I have a Django model as follows:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field1 = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
    my_field2 = models.DateTimeField()
```

It works:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.all()
[<MyModel: MyModel object>, <MyModel: MyModel object>,
```

Now I add the following constructor to `MyModel`:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    if self.my_field2 is None:
        self.my_field2 = self.my_field1
```

And that breaks the class:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MYvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 138, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "MYvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 162, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "MYvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 965, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "MYvirtualenv/src/django-cache-machine-master/caching/base.py", line 118, in __iter__
    obj = iterator.next()
  File "MYvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 255, in iterator
    obj = model_cls.from_db(db, init_list, row[model_fields_start:model_fields_end])
  File "MYvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 489, in from_db
    new = cls(*values)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Why does this happen when I add the relatively simple constructor? How should I remedy it? I need the logic in that constructor, so I cannot just eliminate it.

Comment: You have `MyModel` everywhere but `Prediction` in the constructor. Did you just forget to sanitize it or are you actually calling the wrong class by accident?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the args. def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: @Anonymous. Yes. That was a sanitation error. Sorry. Fixed now.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580/writing-a-init-function-to-be-used-in-django-model for a similar discussion.

Comment: don't use __init__ i've added an answer to your other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force 2 fields in a Django model to share the same default value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782083/how-can-i-force-2-fields-in-a-django-model-to-share-the-same-default-value)

Comment: This is not a follow up but a duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

Although, you're strongly advised to use a `classmethod` or a custom manager in the docs, your code would not work because you have modified the calling signature of the `superclass`, which should have been:

```
super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can avoid doing this by using a `classmethod`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field1 = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
    my_field2 = models.DateTimeField()

    @classmethod
    def sync_dates(cls, myfield1):
         my_model = cls(my_field1=myfield1, my_field2=myfield1)
         # do something with my_model
         return my_model
```

And `MyModel.sync_dates(some_date)` does the trick.

Or you could use a custom manager which is the preferred way:

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def create_with_sync_date(self, myfield1):
        my_model = self.create(my_field1=myfield1, my_field2=myfield1)
        # do something with my_model
        return my_model

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field1 = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
    my_field2 = models.DateTimeField()

    objects_synced = MyModelManager()
```

And you can call `MyModel.objects_synced.create_with_sync_date(some_date)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `__init__` in Django models, instead use `Meta` class

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field1 = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
    my_field2 = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'My Model'
        verbose_name_plural = 'My Models' # and so on
```

Comment: This doesn't accomplish the same functionality as the `__init__()` method I showed.

Answer (score 0):

Using **init** is discouraged.
According to Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, title):
        book = cls(title=title)
        # do something with the book
        return book

 book = Book.create("Pride and Prejudice")
```