# How can I force 2 fields in a Django model to share the same default value without repeating populating method?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model `MyModel` as shown below.

It has two fields of type DateTimeField: `my_field1`, `my_field2`

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field1 = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
    my_field2 = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want both fields to default to the value of `datetime.utcnow()`. But I want to save ***the same*** value for both. It seems wasteful to call `utcnow()` twice.

How can I set the default value of `my_field2` so that it simply copies the default value of `my_field1`?

I tried adding an `__init__()` method to `MyModel` like this:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    if self.my_field2 is None:
        self.my_field2 = self.my_field1
```

But doing so broke the model as you can see here:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MYvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 138, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "MYvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 162, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "MYvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 965, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "MYvirtualenv/src/django-cache-machine-master/caching/base.py", line 118, in __iter__
    obj = iterator.next()
  File "MYvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 255, in iterator
    obj = model_cls.from_db(db, init_list, row[model_fields_start:model_fields_end])
  File "MYvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 489, in from_db
    new = cls(*values)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

What is the proper remedy? 
I need the value of `my_field2` to default to the value of `my_field1` (without calling the repeating the call to the default function that populated `my_field1`)

Comment: This looks like the [same question you asked a little while ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782083/how-can-i-force-2-fields-in-a-django-model-to-share-the-same-default-value).

Answer (score 1):

Answer that worked for me:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.my_field2:
        self.my_field2 = self.my_field1
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```