# Failed to retrieve list of Django objects with models.Manager

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have the following structure scenario in my **models.py** :

```
from django.db import models

class SensorManager(models.Manager):
    def create_sensor(self,numero,pinoFisico):
        sensor = self.create(numero = numero,
                             pinoFisico = pinoFisico,
                             ativo      = False)
        return sensor

class Sensor(models.Model):
    numero = models.IntegerField()
    pinoFisico = models.IntegerField()
    ativo = models.BooleanField()
    dataUltimoReconhecimento = models.DateTimeField()
    situacao = None
    moduloSensor = None

    #Manager
    objects = SensorManager()

    def __init__(self):
        self.moduloSensor = ModuloSensor()
```

and, in **views.py** file, i have this:

```
def formSensores(request):
    sensores = Sensor.objects.all()
    print sensores
    return render(request,"speedapp/monitoraSensores.html",{"sensores": sensores})
```

When I try to **use** objects in

> print sensores

i get the following stack:

```
[17/Apr/2017 00:38:09] "GET /speedapp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3649
Internal Server Error: /speedapp/sensores/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/speed_project/speed/speedapp/views.py", line 39, in formSensores
    print sensores
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 234, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 69, in __iter__
    obj = model_cls.from_db(db, init_list, row[model_fields_start:model_fields_end])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in from_db
    new = cls(*values)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (6 given)
[17/Apr/2017 00:38:11] "GET /speedapp/sensores/ HTTP/1.1" 500 15557
```

As the stack, it seems to be a problem at the moment of building the `Sensor` object by the `SensorManager` method in the `__init__()` method in class `from_db`, where *N* arguments were expected ... this problem is related to the my Custom Manager `SensorManager`?

P.S:

1. This error does not happens for other objects that are also used with the "all()" method through `models.Manager`, only for this `Sensor` class
2. Only happen when i try "use" instance of list objects, get with `all()` method, for example: print the value of it
3. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802041/why-does-adding-this-init-method-break-my-django-model) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782083/how-can-i-force-2-fields-in-a-django-model-to-share-the-same-default-value) related questions in my search, But I could not solve my problem with them

Comment: For debugging purposes, you could try (1) unplugging your custom model manager and (2) ensure you made and ran migrations. 

Also, could you explain why you have set `situacao` and `moduloSensor` to `None`?

Comment: Apparently,, this is not  your exact code - can you update your question with your exact code (only relevant pieces)

Comment: @karthikr I agree with you, I think the question can be improved, but it already contains the exact pieces of my code or, relevant pieces. I call the `formSensores` method and the exception occurs after call `Sensor.objects.all()` in `print sensores`. The same problem happens if I try to simulate directly in the django python shell ( `python manage.py shell` ).

Comment: @raiderrobert I unplugging the manager, commenting on objects of the `Sensor` class, the error continues. The database schema is properly updated with `makemigrations` and `migrate`. The fields `situacao` and `moduloSensor` are not persisted, so they receive None. I use them in some methods only for support in memory, a similar approach to `@Transient` from Hibernate in Java, but if there is a better solution I'm listening.

Comment: @DarlynVailatti, so I think you're using the Django 1.9.x branch. Not sure it's very important to the conversation, but I figured I'd note it, and further, that this very section of code got refactored in 1.10: https://github.com/django/django/blame/1.10/django/db/models/base.py#L460  All that said, I replicated your code, and I had no problem running it. So either you have a perfect storm of circumstances, or you've omitted something inadvertently.

Comment: @raiderrobert yeah, i'm using django 1.9.5 (`python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"`) I updated the question by inserting the code that was missing in the class `Sensor`.

Comment: The problem is the __init__ on the model. Django uses that. So you shouldn't do that. May I ask why you are?

Comment: @raiderrobert yeah, i removed `__init__()` and it worked. I'm using this method because i want initialize `moduloSensor` field, but it means this is not right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's the high level answer. The problem is that you were overriding the `__init__` method on the model. You really, really should try to avoid that. Here's some documentation on other options; read the big green note: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model

Here's an excerpt:

`You may be tempted to customize the model by overriding the __init__ method...Rather than overriding __init__, try using one of these approaches
1. Add a classmethod on the model class
2. Add a method on a custom manager (usually preferred)`

If you absolutely need to override `__init__`, then don't forget to call `super()` pass the values down, and let Django do its stuff first.